# eval elisp code to fill org-babel header arguments

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I use many org files with figures generated by source code blocks.

By example, in an org mode file *long/path/document.org* I have:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC dot :file my_fig.png  :exports results
digraph {
  A->B
  B->C
  C->A
}
#+END_SRC
```

However, to keep a clean directory/files hierarchy I want store the generated figures (or data) in a subdirectory associated to each org mode document, for instance: *long/path/document-extra/my_fig.png*.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC dot :file long/path/document-extra/my_fig.png  :exports results
digraph {
  A->B
  B->C
  C->A
}
#+END_SRC
```

Doing that manually is tedious, how to automate this?

Answer (score 3):

I define functions at the end of my org mode file (thanks [Local variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html#Specifying-File-Variables))

```
#+BEGIN_SRC dot :file (fig_name "my_fig") :exports results
digraph {
  A->B
  B->C
  C->A
}
#+END_SRC

...

# end of my org mode file

# Local Variables:
# eval: (defun fig_name(name) (concat (file-name-sans-extension (buffer-file-name)) "-extra/" name ".png"))
# End:
```

The function `(fig_name "my_fig")` automatically creates the right filename, something like:

```
: /home/XXX/GitLab/YYY/Bibliography/jiang11_rankin_hodge_theor-notes-extra/my_fig.png
```

As defined we assumed that the directory *long/path/document-extra/* exists, but this can be also checked and eventually created in the `fig_name` function.